# OAuth2 Authentication to Gmail throws SunCertPathBuilderException/SSLHandshakeException

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, imap

In my app i authenticate to Gmail using the OAuth2Authenticator from [this Google example](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/source/browse/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/oauth2/OAuth2Authenticator.java) to receive Emails via Imap.

The code works perfect, but the last days some users reported an error that occurs when they try to connect to Gmail.

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>   Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>   failed    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source) Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

The ImapSSLStore conncets to "imap.gmail.com" on port 993.

This does not happen to all users and occurs not before last week.

Is anybody observing this behaviour too? 
Hints appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your system's X.509 configuration for verifying the SSL certificates is not treating the Google's certificate as a trusted one. This might have various reasons.

Comment: Okay, its strange that it worked for the user before last week and for some it is still working. Can you give me an idea where i can start?